# VirtualBox starts up for install and then won't accept input

Tags: virtualbox, debian, installation, arch-linux

I am trying to set up a VM using virtual box. I tried with debian and then arch. In each case the VM starts up and I see the initial installation screen (see below) but no key presses and no mouse clicks work at all. I am not too sure what is wrong. I assume it is something really simple, but I can't find anything that would be out of place. Perhaps a bios setting is needed by VirtualBox to accept keyboard and mouse in the VM? See photo below of how far I can get before it stops accepting input.
[image]

Comment: VT-d is not required, to run 64-bit VMs, your thinking of VT-x.  The author’s question has nothing to do with VT-x or VT-d since the VM clearly is working.

Comment: “Perhaps a bios setting is needed by VirtualBox to accept keyboard and mouse in the VM?” - This most definitely is not the case.

Comment: I found this in the log file. However I didn't see anything useful when I searched for the error code.
```
ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) 
aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} 
aComponent={KeyboardWrap} 
aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard 
(VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, 
preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
```

Answer (score 0):

I still can't comment but let me help you, maybe far simple I just need to know: 1. what is your base system you are running virtual box on? If its Debian there are a few things to do to solve the issue like installing header files and 2. How did you install virtual box, what version, what repository - everything you done to install virtual box because it can be confused by installing the host and client system because both can be installed at once on Debian.

I will edit my answer after you commented.